# Error: illegal start of expression followed by PriorityQueue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am doing leetcode practicing and have the following piece of code:

```
    PriorityQueue<int[]> q=new PriorityQueue<int[]>(new Comparator<int[]>(){
        public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2){
            return o1[0]-o2[0];
        }
    });
    q.add([0,1]);
    q.add([1,1]);
    q.add([2,1]);
```

where I got

```
Line 10: error: illegal start of expression
```

I really wonder what's the problem of this code?

Comment: Line 10 is not 'followed by `PriorityQueue`'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is in the way you try to create the int arrays.

In java you cannot use square braces like [1,2,3] to create arrays.
Instead, try something like

`q.add(new int[] {1,2});`